# Group Law Elliptic Curve with Divisor Class Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and $k$ a field. It is well know that $E(k)$ has an (additive) group structure and indeed there are a lot of sources describing what geometrically there is going on.

The point of my interest is to find a derivation of this group law in language of divisors - especially using properties of the ***divisor class group***.

Indeed the divisors $Div(E)$ are formal sums $\sum_{P \in E(k)} n_P (P)$ with $n_P \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the principal divisors $div(f) = \sum_P ord_P(f) (P)$ form a subgroup of $Div(E)$; denote it by $PrDiv(E)$.

The divisor class group is the quotient $Cl(E)= Div(E)/PrDiv(E)$.

Obviosly we can define canonically a map $E(k) \to Cl(E), p \to (P)-(O)$ where $O$ is the special point (=neutral element).

How to show that this map determine the group law on $E(k)$.

Comment: $(O)$ isn't a principal divisor. Principal divisors have degree zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: ah sure sure, $(O)-(O)$ should be the prinipal one and is obviously one. Thank you. But the point is why in $Cl(E)$ the group law is already determined.

Comment: This is Proposition III.3.4 (p. 61) in Silverman. Have you looked there?

Comment: Every degree zero divisor is congruent, modulo principal divisors, to exactly one of the form $(P)-(O)$.

Comment: It suffices to show (or define) that $P+Q-R-O$ is a principal divisor iff $P + Q= R$ in the group law. From this then $\sum_j P_j-Q_j = R-O+div(f)$ where $R = \sum_j P_j-Q_j$ in the group law and $div(f) = O-R+\sum_j P_j-Q_j$ where $f$ is meromorphic

Comment: @reuns: Ok so $P+Q-R-O = div(g)$ for some $g$ "defines" the group law. Obviously it's well defined since for another $R'$ with $P+Q-R'-O = div(g')$ we would get $R - R' = div(g) -div(g')$, so far looks good. What I don't understand is what do you mean by the line $\sum_j P_j-Q_j = R-O+div(f)$? What is the sum $\sum_j P_j-Q_j$?

Comment: $\sum_j P_j-Q_j$ is any degree zero divisor. $\sum_j (P_j+R_j-Q_j-O)$ is principal so the game is to show $\sum_j (R_j-O)  +O-R$ is principal, by applying $p+q-O = r+div(u)$ several times. At the end $Div^0(E)/Prin(E) \cong E$ and $Div(E)/Prin(E) \cong E \times \langle O \rangle $ where $\langle O \rangle  \subset Div(E)$

Comment: @reuns:One point seems unclear: Is the statement that $P+Q-R-O$ is a principal divisor a conclusion from the the properties of $Cl(E)$ or a definition. Above I explained (hope with acorrect argument) that if such $R$ suffice the equation above that it must be unique. What I not see up to now is why such $R$ in $Cl(E)$ should exist?

Comment: Riemann-Roch and genus $1$ means given $P,Q$, there is a unique $R$ such that $P+Q-R- O$ is principal. It is a group with $O$ as identity. Otherwise from the group law on $y^2= f(x), f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^3 (x-e_j)$ and $P = S+T, Q = S-T,R =P+Q=2S$ and $u((x,y)) = \frac{1}{x+e_1-x_T}$ and $v((x,y)) = u((x,y)-S)-u(-S)$
then $u((x,y)) = u(-(x,y))$ so $v(R) =v(2S) = u(S)-u(-S)= 0$ and $div(u) = 2O-T-(-T), div(v)=O+R-P-Q$

Comment: @reuns: I'm not sure how the Riemann Roch argument here works: RR says that for a divisor $D$ of $E$ that $$l(D)-l(K-D) = deg(D) +g-1$$ holds. We have $l(D) := dim_kH^0(D, \mathcal{O}_D)$ and since $E$ elliptic $g=1$ as you pointed out. 

My attempt: As divisor I take $D:= P + Q -O$. Then $deg(D) =2-1=1$. But how to cope with $l(D)$ and especially $l(K-D)$ for the canonical divisor $K$? Is $K$ it principal. Could you explain how do you conclude the existence of $R$ such $P+Q-R- O$ is principal using Riemann Roch?

Comment: On a complex torus $dz$ is an holomorphic differential, it becomes $\frac{d\wp(z)}{\wp'(z)} = \frac{dx}{y}$ on the curve $y^2= 4x^3-ax-b$, so $D = P+Q,K = div(\frac{dx}{y})=\emptyset, \ell(K-D) = 0,\ell(D) = \ell(K-D)+\deg(D)-g+1 =\deg(D)=2$ so there is $v$ non-constant with $div(v) = A+B-P-Q$ and $div(u-u(O)) = R+O-P-Q$

Comment: @reuns: so $div(v) = A+B-P-Q$ because $deg(div(v))=0$ and $v \in L(D) = \{r \vert div(r) + D \ge 0 \}$? What is $u$? Seems to be another global section from $L(D)$. How does it relate to $v$?